# Dynamic HTML content and Python variables with Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

On the user end, say I have people selecting school records through a form to display in a table below.

For instance, they choose their name from a list of names, and that pulls their records from a database.

Dependent on their class year, they may have 1, 2, 3, or 4 years of records, so the data pulled will always look different.

After they submit the form, their records are stored in a variable containing all their records, and then each record is broken down into subtypes, for instance, all records in the English department. Those subtypes are stored in other lists--so there's a list for all English records. Let's call that variable english_records. I want to use these subtype variables to be able to present only the data users want to see, and to present all data in that particular list.

So using Flask's render_template function, I'm trying to send each of these records to an html template that will create a table cell for each record.

What I've been trying (that hasn't worked so far) is something like:

**Python:**

```
i = 0
def index():
    for e in english_records:
        english_records = [
            { 
                'english': english_records[i]
            }
        ]
        i = i + 1
    return render_template("index.html",
        english_records = english_records)
```

**And in HTML:**

```
...table above...
{% for record in english_records %}
<td>
  {{record.english}}
</td>
{% endfor %}
...table continues...
```

Thus far I've been getting table cells created for each record, but the records not being passed through. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you're pre-processing the data? What does `english_records` look like? If my hunch is correct, then you shouldn't actually need the `for` loop at all.

There's also the issue that you're overwriting the initial `english_records` variable with `english_records` within the for loop, so the assignment, while legal in terms of syntax, is logically nonsensical.

Another issue is that, depending on the actual type of the first `english_records`, you shouldn't need to use a counter: if `english_records` is a `list`, then it'll contain the value you're looking for. If `english_records` is a `dict`, then enumerating it might look like `for key, val in english_records.iteritems()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for e in english_records:
        english_records = [
            { 
                'english': english_records[i]
            }
        ]
        i = i + 1
```

This loop here is creating a list , but the members of those list do not have 'english' key ,
so in the template, the loop is executed, but there is no value for `{{record.english}}` , hence it is ignored.
All you will get is table rows without any data.

Comment: So how could I fix that? Isn't the 4th line giving that key?