# How to display a variable in HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I am making a web app using Python and have a variable that I want to display on an HTML page. How can I go about doing so? Would using `{% VariableName %}` in the HTML page be the right approach to this?

Comment: Could you be more specific on how you are using python with your web app? Are you using Django?

Comment: you sure your question is not already answered thousands of times and googling for it is of no use?

Comment: @RobertPounder I am using Flask. Have information on an API saved as a variable and wish to display this on a HTML page

Comment: That would certainly be the right approach if you were using a templating language that supported it and passing `VariableName` to the template... but are you? Could you give a [mcve]? Why not just try it and see?

Comment: `{{variablename}}`

Should work.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975114/dynamic-html-content-and-python-variables-with-flask

Comment: Funny enough, this is the first result in Google for 'flask html use variable' and actually helped me.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is very clearly explained in the Flask [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#rendering-templates) so I recommend that you read it for a full understanding, but here is a very simple example of rendering template variables.

HTML template file stored in `templates/index.html`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Here is my variable: {{ variable }}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And the simple Flask app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask('testapp')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', variable='12345')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Run this script and visit http://127.0.0.1:5000/ in your browser. You should see the value of `variable` rendered as `12345`

Comment: thanks! but what if my variable is declared into a class?