# How to use python variable in HTML code

Tags: python, html

```
import sys
variable=sys.argv[1]
#print variable

"""<html>
<body>
    <p>Here is my variable: {{variable}} </p>
</body>"""
```

Question: Question:   Hi , 
    I am trying to get python variable inside HTML code . below is sample code .

```
File : test.py  Hell

I want output just Hello on screen . Please give any advice . 

Thanks  and Regards ,
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965558/how-to-display-a-variable-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a variable in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965558/how-to-display-a-variable-in-html)

Comment: Curiously, you also get duplicate duplicate flags!