# Passing a variable from python to HTML page

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have a long python function and within the function I am generating a voucher which I would want to autofill in my HTML page. Kindly assist

The full function:

```
def confirmation(request):
    print("Start MpesaCallback")
    global profile
    
    mpesa_body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    mpesa_body = json.loads(mpesa_body)
    print(mpesa_body)
    print("Mpesa Body")

    merchant_requestID = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["MerchantRequestID"]
    print('merchant_requestID: ', merchant_requestID)
    checkout_requestID = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CheckoutRequestID"]
    print('checkout_requestID: ', checkout_requestID)
    result_code = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultCode"]
    print('result_code: ', result_code)
    result_desc = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultDesc"]
    print('result_desc: ', result_desc)
    metadata = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"]
    for item in metadata:
        title = item["Name"]
        if title == "Amount":
            amount = item["Value"]
            print('Amount: ', amount)
        elif title == "MpesaReceiptNumber":
            mpesa_receipt_number = item["Value"]
            print('Mpesa Reference No: ', mpesa_receipt_number)
        elif title == "TransactionDate":
            transaction_date = item["Value"]
            print('Transaction date: ', transaction_date)
        elif title == "PhoneNumber":
            phone_number = item["Value"]
            print('Phone Number: ', phone_number)

    str_transaction_date = str(transaction_date)
    trans_datetime = datetime.strptime(str_transaction_date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    tz_trans_datetime = pytz.utc.localize(trans_datetime)

    payment = MpesaPayment.objects.create(
        MerchantRequestID=merchant_requestID,
        CheckoutRequestID=checkout_requestID,
        ResultCode=result_code,
        ResultDesc=result_desc,
        Amount=amount,
        MpesaReceiptNumber=mpesa_receipt_number,
        TransactionDate=tz_trans_datetime,
        PhoneNumber=phone_number,
    )
    if result_code == 0:
        payment.save()
        print("Successfully saved")

        password_length = 5
        voucher = secrets.token_urlsafe(password_length)

        print(voucher)

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'h_api_key': os.getenv("SMS_Token"),
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        payload = {
            "mobile": phone_number,
            "response_type": "json",
            "sender_name": "23107",
            "service_id": 0,
            "message": "Your WiFi Voucher is " + voucher + ".\nAirRumi."
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", 'https://smsdomain.com/sms/sendsms', headers=headers,
                                    json=payload)
        r = response.json()
        print(r)
        print("SMS Sent")

        print(amount)

        if amount == 1:
            profile = 'one_hour'
        elif amount == 50:
            profile = 'one_day'
        elif amount == 300:
            profile = 'one_week'
        elif amount == 1000:
            profile = 'one_month'
        else:
            print('Incorrect Amount')

        print(profile)

        connection = routeros_api.RouterOsApiPool(
            host=os.getenv("ip"),
            username=os.getenv("usernamee"),
            password=os.getenv("password"),
            port=8728,
            use_ssl=False,
            ssl_verify=False,
            ssl_verify_hostname=True,
            ssl_context=None,
            plaintext_login=True
        )
        api = connection.get_api()

        user = api.get_resource('/ip/hotspot/user')
        user.add(name=voucher, server="hotspot1", password='1234', profile=profile)

        print("User " + voucher + " created.")

    else:
        print("Payment was not successful")

    context = {
        "resultcode": result_code,
        "resultdesc": result_desc
    }

    if context['resultcode'] == 0:
        return JsonResponse(dict(context))
```

My HTML page that I want auto filled:

```
<form name="login" action="http://mydomain/login" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="https://www.google.com"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true"/>

                <label>
                   <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ voucher }}" placeholder="Enter your Voucher" required>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="1234">
                </label><br><br>
                <div id="login-button"><input type="submit" value="CONNECT"/></div>
            </form>
```

How do I get the voucher generated and auto fill it in the HTML? I have used the {{ voucher }} and its not working.
I have updated the whole function but not the whole view.py

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31966504/19152434 <br/>
Maybe use something like flask?

Comment: Do you use `Django`?

Comment: What framework do you use?

Comment: Am using Django

Comment: you have to use `render` to process your template and pass your voucher (or response) in `context` parameter?

Comment: How? ,I have no idea

Comment: Do you have a views.py file in your app?

Comment: Yes, it where the fuction is

Comment: Can you update your post with the whole function?

Comment: Its as though I do not have that option

Comment: What do you mean, you can't edit your own question?

Comment: I have updated the whole function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/) for `django.shortcuts` module:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def confirmation(request):
   # Your code here
   ...
    context = {
        "resultcode": result_code,
        "resultdesc": result_desc,
        "voucher": voucher,  # <- HERE
    }

    # Comment
    # if context['resultcode'] == 0:
    #    return JsonResponse(dict(context))

   return render(request, 'your_template.html', context=context)
```

Comment: return render(request, 'your_template.html', context={'voucher': voucher}) this should be the last line in the function?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Its still not retrieving the voucher

Comment: You have to modify the end of your function. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, working well in postman, let me try in production.

Comment: I have tried to return the filled html on production but its not working, where could I be messing up?

Comment: The code did not work, but when I define the voucher formula at the very top it works, problems is I want triggered by the payment not on system start

Comment: What do you mean by "The code did not work". You have an exception, the `voucher` is empty, etc?

Comment: The function is a call back so it does not display the context frontend, but when I run it on postman it shows well, How do i fetch it?

Comment: Check it out here, the code and the output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75545923/works-well-in-postman-but-not-production