# Works well in Postman but not production

Tags: html, python-3.x, django

I want to display a variable generated in views.py in my login.html
The views.py generates a username(voucher) and I want it auto filled in my login.html
In the function the mpesa_body are details from a callback so it neither a GET nor POST.

```
def confirmation(request):
    print("Start MpesaCallback")
    global profile, voucher

    mpesa_body = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    mpesa_body = json.loads(mpesa_body)
    print(mpesa_body)
    print("Mpesa Body")

    merchant_requestID = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["MerchantRequestID"]
    print('merchant_requestID: ', merchant_requestID)
    checkout_requestID = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CheckoutRequestID"]
    print('checkout_requestID: ', checkout_requestID)
    result_code = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultCode"]
    print('result_code: ', result_code)
    result_desc = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["ResultDesc"]
    print('result_desc: ', result_desc)
    metadata = mpesa_body["Body"]["stkCallback"]["CallbackMetadata"]["Item"]
    for item in metadata:
        title = item["Name"]
        if title == "Amount":
            amount = item["Value"]
            print('Amount: ', amount)
        elif title == "MpesaReceiptNumber":
            mpesa_receipt_number = item["Value"]
            print('Mpesa Reference No: ', mpesa_receipt_number)
        elif title == "TransactionDate":
            transaction_date = item["Value"]
            print('Transaction date: ', transaction_date)
        elif title == "PhoneNumber":
            phone_number = item["Value"]
            print('Phone Number: ', phone_number)

    str_transaction_date = str(transaction_date)
    trans_datetime = datetime.strptime(str_transaction_date, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    tz_trans_datetime = pytz.utc.localize(trans_datetime)

    payment = MpesaPayment.objects.create(
        MerchantRequestID=merchant_requestID,
        CheckoutRequestID=checkout_requestID,
        ResultCode=result_code,
        ResultDesc=result_desc,
        Amount=amount,
        MpesaReceiptNumber=mpesa_receipt_number,
        TransactionDate=tz_trans_datetime,
        PhoneNumber=phone_number,
    )
    if result_code == 0:
        payment.save()
        print("Successfully saved")

        password_length = 5
        voucher = secrets.token_urlsafe(password_length)

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'h_api_key': os.getenv("SMS_Token"),
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
        payload = {
            "mobile": phone_number,
            "response_type": "json",
            "sender_name": "23107",
            "service_id": 0,
            "message": "Your WiFi Voucher is " + voucher + ".\nAirRumi: 0710671768."
        }
        response = requests.request("POST", 'https://api.mobitechtechnologies.com/sms/sendsms', headers=headers,
                                    json=payload)
        r = response.json()
        print(r)
        print("SMS Sent")

        print(amount)

        if amount == 1:
            profile = 'one_hour'
        elif amount == 30:
            profile = '12_hours'
        elif amount == 50:
            profile = 'one_day'
        elif amount == 250:
            profile = 'one_week'
        elif amount == 450:
            profile = '2_weeks'
        elif amount == 900:
            profile = 'one_month'
        else:
            print('Incorrect Amount')

        print(profile)

        connection = routeros_api.RouterOsApiPool(
            host=os.getenv("ip"),
            username=os.getenv("usernamee"),
            password=os.getenv("password"),
            port=8728,
            use_ssl=False,
            ssl_verify=False,
            ssl_verify_hostname=True,
            ssl_context=None,
            plaintext_login=True
        )
        api = connection.get_api()

        user = api.get_resource('/ip/hotspot/user')
        user.add(name=voucher, server="hotspot1", password='1234', profile=profile)

        print("User " + voucher + " created.")

    else:
        print("Payment was not successful")

    template = "login.html"
    context = {
        # "resultcode": result_code,
        # "resultdesc": result_desc,
        "voucher": voucher,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

When I run it on postman it works well but not on the browser.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

NOt sure but kindly check the typo at the line

```
// is this "usernamee" or "username" ?
username=os.getenv("usernamee"),
```

Do you have the username key spelled as defined? Might be the typo problem.

Comment: The typo is intentional, its okay, but that voucher is still not displaying on production